# Undefined variable $attendance_status using radio button laravel

Tags: laravel

i am using laravel query builder but the problem is i am using radio buttons but i want to update the attendance at the radio button but it returns an error Undefined variable $attendance_status
i don't know why please help and how can i pass the $attendance_status variable

here is my code

my form

```
<form action="{{route('Attendances.update',$student->id)}}" method="post">
                   @csrf
                   @method('PUT')
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$student->id}}">
                   <label class="block text-gray-500 font-semibold sm:border-r sm:pr-4">
                       <input name="attendences"
                              {{ $student->attendances()->first()->attendence_status == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}
                              class="leading-tight" type="radio" value="presence">
                       <span class="text-success">حضور</span>
                   </label>

                   <label class="ml-4 block text-gray-500 font-semibold">
                       <input name="attendences"
                       {{ $student->attendances()->first()->attendence_status == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}
                              class="leading-tight" type="radio" value="absent">
                              <span class="text-danger">غياب</span>
                   </label>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                               data-dismiss="modal">{{trans('Students_trans.Close')}}</button>
                               <button class="btn btn-danger">{{trans('Students_trans.submit')}}</button>
                            </div>
               </form>
```

here is my controller
update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // return $request;

        if($request->attendances == 'absent'){
            $attendance_status = 0;
        }
        else if($request->attendances == 'presence'){
            $attendance_status = 1;
        }
        Attendance::find($id)->update([
            'student_id'=> $id,
            'grade_id'=> $request->grade_id,
            'class_id'=> $request->classroom_id,
            'section_id'=> $request->section_id,
            'attendance_date'=> date('Y-m-d'),
            'status' => $attendance_status,
    ]);

    return back();
```

Comment: Why not set `value="0"` and `value="1"` instead of `value="absent"` and `value="present"`; then you wouldn't need the `$attendance_status` at all, you'd just do `'status' => $request->input('attendences', 0)` (with a fallback to `0` if neither Radio is selected)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `if` and an `elseif` in your Controller, so only 2 conditions would create a variable named `$attendance_status`. You probably want to add a default branch, `else` basically, to make sure that the variable gets created with some **default** value before you try to use it in your `update` call.

Not sure which one of those 2 options you want to be the default but this would simplify things:

```
$attendance_status = $request->attendences == 'presence';
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

> You may use the `withInput` method provided by the `RedirectResponse` instance to flash the current request's input data to the session before redirecting the user to a new location. Once the input has been flashed to the session, you may easily retrieve it during the next request:
>
> ```
> return back()->withInput();
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Surely `{{ $student->attendances()->first()->attendence_status == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }}` logic does not work in this way.
try this instead

```
 <input name="attendences" checked="{{ $student->attendances()->first()->attendence_status == 0 ? true : false}}" class="leading-tight" type="radio" value="absent">
```